# render in html_requests return none

Tags: python, html, python-requests, python-requests-html

I used render, links in python_requests return `None`, `set()`

I dont know where the problem is?

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('http://saipa.iranecar.com/')
print(r.html.render())  # None
```

dont have any error

Comment: Would you please expand more on the problem? What exactly are you trying to access here? Expected output?

Comment: when i tried in other website return dict. but this website return None

Comment: i want get all html code from website.

Comment: first i used python requests library return some code, does not show all element
then used request_html return None

Comment: seems the website is using generated javascript and after checking it seems it's heavily obfuscated to prevent bots. I suggest you check ```Selenium``` out.

Comment: Thank you for your suggest.
I checked this way(selenium). that's very slow...dont want use gui programing

Comment: Well what you could do is try to reverse-engineer the  javascript code and get it all working with ```requests```. I've checked the js file and it's very large, so i assume it wont be an easy task. You can try projects like [this](https://github.com/eth-sri/UnuglifyJS) to deobfuscate the javascript, or something like [this](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py) to convert the javascript to python.  However all of this will take some time and gui programming would be an easier albeit slower solution to this whole situation.

Comment: Thanks,  i'll use this lib maybe works well.
I can't speak english very well, excuse me

Answer (score 3):

r.html.render() is done in place.  Therefore it should be done outside of the print function

```
...
r.html.render()
print (r.content)
```